# Mouse listener in button to change click count in label

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jlabel

How can I put `MouseListener` in `JButton` so that a `JLabel` changes to the no. of times the button is clicked?

I created a frame with a button and a label` using a mouse listener. The label of the frame shows the no. of times the button is clicked.
I tried using the below program :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class Bevent implements ActionListener
{
JFrame jf=new JFrame("BUTTON EVENT");
JButton jb=new JButton("CLICK !");
JLabel jl=new JLabel("CLicked 0 times");
int count=0;
Bevent()
{
jf.setSize(500,500);
jf.setLayout(null);
jf.setVisible(true);
jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(jf.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
jb.setBounds(100,100,100,30);
jf.add(jb);
jl.setBounds(100,200,200,30);
jf.add(jl);
jb.addActionListener(this);
}
public static void main(String arg[])
{
new Bevent();
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
count=count+1;
jl.setText("CLicked "+count+" times");
jf.add(jl);
}
}
```

Is it an efficient code for the problem.

Comment: *".. am getting a runtime error. Suggest any method."* Fix the code. If you want *our* help in doing that, post a [mre] and the text of the runtime error. BTW - please take more care with the tags used. This has problem **nothing** to do with databases, and **everything** to do with Java, Swing components and the AWT based mouse listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ButtonClick{
    JFrame frame;
    JLabel label;
    JButton button;
    int count = 1;
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ButtonClick gui = new ButtonClick();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go(){
        frame = new JFrame();

        button = new JButton("Click me");
        button.addActionListener(new ClickListener());

        label = new JLabel("Clicked 0 times");

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, button);
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST, label);

        frame.setSize(400,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class ClickListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            label.setText("Clicked " + count + " times");
            count += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above, the `JButton` has a `ClickListener` which sets the `JLabel`'s text to the number of times(instance variable count) the `JButton` was pressed.